# Multiple war in Tomcat 7 using a shared embedded ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, tomcat7

I'm working on a project where I have several war files inside a tomcat 7 have to communicate with a single embedded activeMQ (5.5.1) broker inside the same Tomcat.

I'm wondering what was the best practice to manage this and how to start and stop the broker properly.

Actually I try tu use a global JNDI entry in `server.xml` and in each war gets my activemq connection with a lookup. The first connection to the broker implicitly starts it. But with this method I run into various problems like instance already existing or locks in data store.

Should I use instead an additional war which uses a BrokerFactory to start the broker explicitly? In this case how to make sure that this war executes first in Tomcat ? And how do I stop my broker and where?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

from the docs...

> If you are using the VM transport and wish to explicitly configure an
>   Embedded Broker there is a chance that you could create the JMS
>   connections first before the broker starts up. Currently ActiveMQ will
>   auto-create a broker if you use the VM transport and there is not one
>   already configured. (In 5.2 it is possible to use the waitForStart and
>   create=false options for the connection uri)
>
> So to work around this if you are using Spring you may wish to use the
>   depends-on attribute so that your JMS ConnectionFactory depends on the
>   embedded broker to avoid this happening. e.g.

see these pages for more information...

http://activemq.apache.org/vm-transport-reference.html

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-restart-embedded-broker.html